# How to connect database by using username and password in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to .net c#, hope this question is not sound silly. How can I connect to the database in web.config by using the username and password??

Example:

Following is the connection strings that I used to connect to the database. How could I write/set so that I can set the username (username = test) and password (password = abc123) for this connection strings and so that it will allows me to access to the database?

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="aConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=AAA-LLLL-SQL-00;Initial Catalog=Database_Name;Connect Timeout=1;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  Windows authentication is far more secure -- since not having to put passwords in easily readable config files is a Good Thing.

Comment: see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 - this should be obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="aConnectionString" connectionString="Data
 Source=AAA-LLLL-SQL-00;Initial Catalog=Database_Name;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>   
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: More general: Check http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for most used database connection string variants. Beats most documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to pull your connection string from the web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Then you will use the .net Sql Provider to create a connection.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{

   con.Open();
   // Perform operations here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying from IIS?
Then you need to grant your App Pools account access to SQL Server.

```
CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[AAA-LLLL-SQL-00], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO
```

Comment: While this is one of the ways Microsoft says you can do it I myself have always believed this to be a hack.  I really think they missed the boat on using Windows Auth with IIS and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Reference for ADO and ADO.NET connection strings http://www.sqlstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="aConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=AAA-LLLL-SQL-00;Initial Catalog=Database_Name; User Id=your username; Password=pwd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="aConnectionString" connectionString="Server={ip};Database= {databasename}; User Id={username}; Password={password}"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

This should work replace {...} with your values.